# Perf benchmark - Delay between send request to API and request received in API

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to mesure duration process on my API.

For that, I'm using a simple code which call *n* time the API at the same time.

```
    private HttpClient _httpClient { get; } = new HttpClient();

    [TestCase]
    public async Task Perf_ExecuteAuthThreads()
    {
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(0, NB_THREADS).ToList(), new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = NB_THREADS
        }, async (item, cancellationToken) => await CreateAuthThread(item));
    }

   private async Task CreateAuthThread(int i)
    {
        string tokenAuth = string.Empty;

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

        var stopWatchGlobal = new Stopwatch();
        var stopWatchDetails = new Stopwatch();
        
        stopWatchGlobal.Restart();
        try
        {
            stopWatchDetails.Restart();

            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, RequestFactory.GetRoute(RequestFactory.RequestType.AUTH));
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            request.Content = JsonContent.Create(RequestFactory.CreateRequest(RequestFactory.RequestType.AUTH));

            // Authenticate Method
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            stopWatchDetails.Stop();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                tokenAuth = (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Token>())!.JwtToken;
            }
            else
            {
                string responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //Assert.Fail("Internal server Error : {0}", responseAsString);
            }
        }
        catch {  /* DO NOTHING */ }

        stopWatchGlobal.Stop();

        // Get business transaction Guid
        var transactionGuid = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtEncodedString: tokenAuth).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Constants.JWT_CLAIMS_TRANSACTION_GUID)?.Value ?? null;

        // Thread Id;TransactionGuid;Begin Date;End Date;Auth Duration;Business Duration;Result Business;Total Duration;
        Console.WriteLine($"\"{i}\";\"{transactionGuid}\";\"{startDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")}\";\"{DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")}\";\"{stopWatchDetails.ElapsedMilliseconds}\";\"{(tokenAuth != string.Empty ? true : false)}\";\"{stopWatchGlobal.ElapsedMilliseconds}\"");
    }
```

Assuming my local computer and the server have synchronous clock, I notice that a difference about 3 seconds appears between send request to API and receive request by API. This difference don't exist between the response by API and the end of the call on my computer.

I know transport layers cost time, but 3 seconds appears at expensive.

Do you know if is it possible to reduce this time ? I don't think it's "burst time" (meaning : initialization time of communication)...

My API (and my test code) are on .Net 6 and using TLS connection (HTTPS). Request and Response are classic Json, without a lot of datas.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answerable. Do you measure time between request sent and answer received on local client? Or do you simply compare time stamps of request sent/received on client/server? You write you assume local and server times are synchronized. Don't assume, check it!  What's the ping from local to server? Is the server maybe busy with other things and has a long queue before processing requests? Can you strip out all the work on the server and see whether the delay disappears? Many possible bugs. Other than in the code you posted. Hence not answerable as is.

Comment: Get rid of parallelization, post your server code and try to make a reproducible example. Try without async...

Comment: The testing code is overly complicated for investigating a delay. Don't write any client code. Just send the request through browser dev tools using JavaScript and look at the network tab. It'll show you how long client has to wait and other things. If there's no delay there good. Now increase number of parallel requests, using some CLI or web tool written for this purpose, don't reinvent the wheel when it isn't necessary.

Comment: Do you know any tool which permit to send concurrent queries ?

Comment: There are dozens listed on Github: https://gist.github.com/denji/8333630 e.g. https://github.com/americanexpress/baton